# Rails 4 - Render STI models from a common partial

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sti

I have STI models like this : `Photo < Medium` and `Video < Medium`.
Somewhere in a view, i would like to show them like that :

```
# app/views/albums/show.html.slim
ul
  li= render @album.media
```

The `render` search for a `albums/_photo` or `albums/_video` partial :

```
# app/views/albums/_photo.html.slim
h3= photo.title
= image_tag photo.file.url
p= photo.description

# app/views/albums/_video.html.slim
h3= video.title
= video_tag video.file.url
p= video.description
```

Now, i would like to make a template to use in `app/views/albums/show.html.slim` for not repeat commons fields between media. Something like that :

```
# app/views/albums/_medium.html.slim
h3= medium.title
= yield(:medium_tag)
p= medium.description
= yield(:medium_additionnals)

# app/views/albums/_photo.html.slim
- content_for(:medium_tag) do
  = image_tag photo.file.url
- content_for(:medium_additionnals) do
  # any additionnals fields

# app/views/albums/_video.html.slim
- content_for(:medium_tag) do
  = video_tag video.file.url
- content_for(:medium_additionnals) do
  # any additionnals fields
```

But this give me in yields concatenate contents...

Someone has a solution / alternative to do this ?

[EDIT]

With this templates :

```
# app/views/albums/show.html.slim
= render @album.media

# app/views/albums/_medium.html.slim
div
  h3= medium.title
  = yield(:medium_tag)

# app/views/albums/_photo.html.slim
- content_for(:medium_tag) do
  | TEST
```

The resulting HTML :

```
<div>
  <h3>Photo1</h3>
  TEST
</div>
<div>
  <h3>Photo2</h3>
  TESTTEST
</div>
<div>
  <h3>Photo3</h3>
  TESTTESTTEST
</div>
<div>
  <h3>Photo4</h3>
  TESTTESTTESTTEST
</div>
...
```

The yield result is concatened as many time as media count.

Comment: Can you post the HTML you get from this?

Comment: I edit my question with an example result

Answer (score 1):

Your code seems really good, although I don't get how your `render` call is cycling through each `medium` item

You *could* use a [`helper`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/Helpers.html) to return the relevant data, although that wouldn't be the most efficient:

```
#app/helpers/application_helper.rb
module ApplicationHelper
      output =  Slim::Engine.new  "h3={item.title}"
      output += Slim::Engine.new  "- eval(#{item.model_name.human}_tag) item.file.url"
      output += Slim::Engline.new "p=item.description"
   end
end
```

This would allow you to run:

```
#app/views/albums/_photo.html.slim
= media photo

#app/views/albums/_video.html.slim
= media video
```

-

Alternatively, you could just put it into a `_medium` partial:

```
#app/views/albums/_photo.html.slim
= render partial: "medium", locals: { item: photo }

#app/views/albums/_video.html.slim
= render partial: "medium", locals: { item: video }
```

`_medium` would then have the following:

```
#app/views/albums/_medium.html.slim
h3=item.title
- eval("#{item.model_name.human}_tag") item.file.url
p=item.description
```